# I can't get checkboxes values

Tags: php, html, arrays, post, checkbox

I got this and I have no idea what I'm missing here:

```
<?php
    //Some validation for the SUBMIT form
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['submit']=='add'){
        $_POST = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST); //This little fella is responsible for the mess ¬¬
        $campus_string = $_POST['campus']; //To get a checkboxes Array
        ....
        print_r($campus_string); //to see if I am getting the checkboxes when submitting
    }
?>

....

//Now inside <body> of the HTML
<form action="" method="post" name="filosofal">
    //A little loop to create the checkboxes from a DB
    foreach($campi as $keyCampi => $valueCampi){
        echo '<tr>
                  <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="campus[]" name="campus[]" value="'.$value['Id'].','.$valueCampi['Id'].'" />'.$valueCampi['Nombre'].'<br />
                  </td>
              </tr>';
    }
</form>
```

But `print_r` doesn't show anything, the array is not being stored when submitting via `POST`. Hope you can help me to pinpoint where I'm screwing it.

### EDIT: Solved

Well, I finally figured it out, it's kind of embarrasing.

In my code, I use:

```
$_POST = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST);
```

to avoid some encoding conflicts (like names with 's on them), security and such.

I commented the line and it works now (didn't add that part since I wasn't aware its relevance on the issue), no changes needed to be done.

Don't know why it took me five days to find that little thing over there, but now is done. Anyways, thanks everyone.

Comment: If a checkbox isn't checked when the form is submitted, it won't be present in the `$_POST` array. Is this what you're seeing? You need to use `isset()` to get the 'value' of a checkbox.

Comment: Sidenote: You cannot assign an `id` to `campus[]`. First, the characters `[]` are invalid in an ID. Second, every checkbox rendered would have the same ID, making your code invalid.

Comment: Obviously Im hoping to get the checked values when I´m hitting the submit. 
Basically, I check several boxes, store'em in a array

Comment: why not using var_dump($_POST); ?

Comment: Already did, the values from $_POST['campus'] (the boxes checked), ain't showing

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="add" />
```

Into your form, at the moment your if statement will be returning false...

Answer (score 0):

Try dumping the post data:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
//if you check the radio then it will be listed in your $_POST dump
//add action to your form

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<?php
foreach($campi as $keyCampi => $valueCampi){ 
?>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="campus[]" name="campus[]" value="<?php echo $valueCampi['Id'].','.$valueCampi['Id']; ?>" /><?php echo $valueCampi['Nombre'].'<br />
                  </td>
              </tr>';
    <? php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: 'campus' is empty :/ when checking values

Comment: did you check the checkbox and subitted form..?

Comment: Yes, the complete form includes other inputs (textboxes and radiobuttons). All of them are properly shown in the dump

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, the way I see it is that checkbox is either ON or OFF. Therefore, in my mind, the name of the checkbox is the value.  For instance:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="single"> Single?
```

If that checkbox is checked (value="on"), then the answer is yes. If it is not checked (value="off" or no value), then the answer is no. Therefore, my PHP code looks something like:

```
    if ($_POST['single'] == 'on')
       $single = true;
    else
       $single = false;
```

Basically, as far as I'm concerned, the "value" of a checkbox should never be set. That's my particular preference though, and it's worked well for me. It may not suit your needs, though.

Good luck.

Comment: With this code you will receive an error if the checkbox is not checked. You must test if $_POST['single'] is set, before testing for the value: $single = isset($_POST['single']) && $_POST['single'] === 'on';

Comment: Im not checking if an specific checkbox is checked, but saving the values (a string value from DB) of the checked boxes as an array.

Comment: @macjohn True. You'd receive a warning. It wouldn't be a fatal error though, unless you break on warnings for some reason.

@ Hito_kun Hmm. If you inspect the checkboxes, what are the values set to? I suppose it's possible that if your PHP array is wrong, the values could be set to blank, which would mean you're posting blank... What happens when you print_r($_POST)?

Comment: The value of a checkbox is the `value` attribute's value, it just defaults to `on` if the author fails to specify one. Using `[]` on the end of the name is the standard PHP way to get an array of results (which is what you need in a "Pick any number of these options" form control.

Comment: I checked the values, they are correctly brought from the database (are simple string chains, like 1,1 1,5 etc)

Comment: @Quentin As I said, it's my preference, and I thought it might help Hito's problem. It's clearly not the only way.

Comment: @Hito_kun Hmm. I'm not sure I can help without seeing more code. Sorry. :(

Comment: @Jemaclus http://dl.dropbox.com/u/178339/marca.php 
The whole file, hope you can give it a look